# python type hint field of parent object

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, typing, pydantic

Given the class `User` below, is there any way to type hint the type of the field `User.foo` in the function `f` (without explicitly hard coding `int`)? There are sometimes more complex cases where I would like to be able to refer to the type of a parent objects field directly, derived from the parent type. Is that possible with Python?

```py
import typing

import pydantic


class User(pydantic.BaseModel):
    foo: int


# what type annotation to use for type of User.foo?
# some things i've tried:
#   User.foo
#   typing.Type[User.foo]
#   typing.Type[User].foo
#   typing.Type[User]["foo"]
def f(foo: typing.Type[User].foo):
    print(foo)


user = User(foo=42)
f(user.foo)
```

Whatever I tried so far I always get an error when running `mypy` or when running `python`.

---

**Update**. I think the example I gave above is too simple to really describe the problem. The example below is a bit more realistic. There are some "??" marked where I would like to make a type annotation (something like `Type[TResult.items]`), but can't find a solution.

```py
import abc
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Literal

from pydantic.generics import GenericModel

TResultItem = TypeVar("TResultItem")


class ResultBase(
    GenericModel, Generic[TResultItem]
):
    status: Literal["success", "failure"]
    items: list[TResultItem]


TResult = TypeVar("TResult", bound=ResultBase)


class CalculatorBase(Generic[TResult], abc.ABC):
    def calculate(self) -> TResult:
        try:
            items = []  # items: ??
            for i in range(10):
                items.append(
                    self._calculate_one(i)
                )
        except Exception:
            return self._create_result(
                "failure", []
            )
        else:
            return self._create_result(
                "success", items
            )

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _calculate_one(self, i: int):  # -> ??
        ...

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _create_result(
        self,
        status: Literal["success", "failure"],
        items,  # items: ??
    ) -> TResult:  
        ...
```

---

**Update**. Here's some typescript, I'm basically looking for the python equivalent, if it exists.

```
type User = {
    foo: number;
}

function f(foo: User["foo"]) {
    console.log(foo)
}

const user: User = {foo: 42}
f(user.foo)
```

Comment: `User.foo` is not the type `int`; it's an attribute that can take a *value* of type `int`.

Comment: > User.foo is not the type int; it's an attribute that can take a value of type int
Yes I agree User.foo on it's own is wrong. I'm just wondering if there *is* some notation for this concept...

Comment: Can't say I'm a fan of typing the parameter by relying on the parent type since the function will be written relying on it being an `int` anyway. What complex types are you having that would require this?

Comment: @StevenSummers I've updated the question, tried to give a more realistic example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a variable to abstract the type away from the object:

```
import pydantic

foo_type = int  # holds type of User.foo


class User(pydantic.BaseModel):
    foo: foo_type


def f(foo: foo_type):
    print(foo)


user = User(foo=42)
f(user.foo)
```

Prints:

```
42
```

You could also get the type automatically by using an object of `User`:

```
foo_type = type(User(foo=0).foo)
```

Comment: hmm that's true. i guess it's better than nothing, although i was hoping python would have a nicer solution..